# Base64 encoded file in c# interpreted differently by gmail and yahoo when sent using smtp protocol

Tags: c#, smtp

As For compact framework SMTP client is not supported; I am writting my own SMTP client in c# (to be used in compact framework).

i am sending one image file using SMTP protocol. but it got corrupted when opened in yahoo and works fine in gmail.

```
message = "--sdfsafsafsassfsfsfd" + Constant.CRLF
        + "Content-Type: application/image;" + Constant.CRLF
        + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64;" + Constant.CRLF
        + "Content-Disposition: attachment;" 
        + " filename=abc.jpg;" + Constant.CRLF + Constant.CRLF;
```

following is the code is used to get base64 string for file data.

```
public void SendFile(string fileName)//image/doc file
    {
      string base64;
      using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
        var buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
      }

      Write(base64); 
    }

public void Write(string message)
{
  System.Text.ASCIIEncoding en = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
  byte[] WriteBuffer = new byte[1024 * 5];
  WriteBuffer = en.GetBytes(message);
  NetworkStream stream = GetStream();
  stream.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length);
}
```

i am not understanding if i am missing something. Please help me in this.

Comment: Maybe post the raw source of the message, so we can tell if there's something wrong with it.

Comment: "= new byte[1024 * 5];" -- you don't need this.  en.GetBytes immediately returns a new byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Content-Type: image/jpeg;" instead of "application/image".

Comment: i tried this already but it didnt worked for me. Even i have tried sending word doc file; but result is same.

Comment: You should send yourself a word doc or jpeg via "normal" means and compare headers and the like, and/or you can slog through the RFC to see what else you might be  missing in terms of headers (my guess).

Comment: ok Joe.. thanks for your reply.. i will check RFC once again for this.